# What is the best way to have all the timezones as choices for a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating model which needs to store a timezone value. Right now, I am generating the timezones using `pytz` in another file, converting that into a tuple, and calling that tuple into my **models.py**. Like this:

**timezones.py**

```
import pytz
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = []
for tz in pytz.all_timezones:
    TIMEZONE_CHOICES.append((tz, tz))
TIMEZONE_CHOICES = tuple(TIMEZONE_CHOICES)
```

**models.py**

```
from .timezones import TIMEZONE_CHOICES

class MyModel(models.Model):
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='UTC', choices=TIMEZONE_CHOICES)
```

This honestly seems a bit hack-y. Would generating the timezones this way cause problems in the future? What would be the ideal way to do something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Django allowed [choices to accept callables](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24561) you could simply pass a `lambda` function. But since it doesn't (yet), you should be able to simply define the choices list within your model class and use the `zip` function to dynamically generate the tuples. For example:

```
import pytz

class MyModel(models.Model):
    TIMEZONE_CHOICES = zip(pytz.all_timezones, pytz.all_timezones)

    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='UTC', choices=TIMEZONE_CHOICES)
```

The only issue I can see is that if a timezone is *removed* from the `tz` database in the future, the select box would be empty when you try to edit such a record.